# Plotly date formatting issue for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am using the Plotly python API to upload a pandas dataframe that contains a date column (which is generated via pandas `date_range` function).

If I look at the pandas dataframe locally the date formatting is as I'd expect, i.e YYYY-MM-DD. However, when I view it in Plotly I see it in the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. I really don't need this level of precision and also having such a wide column results in formatting issues when I try to fit all the other columns that I want in.

Is there a way to prevent Plotly from re-formatting the pandas dataframe?

A basic example of my current approach looks like:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(dates)

table = FF.create_table(df)
py.plot(table, filename='example table')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this problem wasn't solvable - Plotly just happened to treat datetimes in that way.

This has since been updated (fixed) - you can read more [here](https://plot.ly/python/table/#Include-and-Index-Column).